# Apple Script to Zoom every active worksheet to required zoom level

Tags: macos, excel, applescript, zooming

I have a workbook with many worksheets. Each time when I switch to a worksheet, I have to zoom it to 150 so as to get the texts visible properly. I want the apple script to do it for me. I use Mac Book Air with Excel 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set zoom of front window to 150
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but when I switch to another worksheet, I have to run the script again. Can it be modified further so that This task is done automatically through the script till excel is running?

Comment: As long as they are all open, this should work:  set zoom of every window to 150

Comment: Thanks, It works first time when the script is run, but when When I switch to a different worksheet, I have to set zoom manually. Can this script be modified to get the zoom to 150 automatically when ever you switch to a different worksheet?